# Why in razor page, background-image: url(~/images/slide.jpg); is not loading image?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I have a razor page app,

If I do

```
<img src="~/images/slide.jpg">
```

It works,

If I do

```
  <div class="item-slick1 item1-slick1" style="background-image: url(~/images/slide.jpg);">
```

It does not work ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use:

```
<div class="item-slick1 item1-slick1" style="background-image: url(../images/slide.jpg);height:100px;"></div>
```

or:

```
<div class="item-slick1 item1-slick1" style="background-image: url('@Url.Content("~/images/slide.jpg")');height:100px;"></div>
```

So that the path will be correct.